# How can I add a submenu to the sidenav in Materialize?

Tags: html, css, materialize

How can I add submenu to the following sidenav?

```
<ul class="sidenav sidenav-fixed" id="nav-mobile" style="width:250px">
  <li> <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Text here</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a onclick="load('home')"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Home</a>
  </li>

  <li><a onclick="load('intro')"><i class="material-icons">apps</i>Content Table</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific ? you can add another unordered list give it a class like 'submenu' adn style it anyway you want like adding a left margin

Answer (score 2):

MaterializeCSS documentation site uses a collapsible inside the sidenav:

https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html

Collapsible is a separate component that also needs initialising:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems);
  });
```

Working codepen:

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/RwPWVqy

The actual markup taken from the Materialize doc site is:

```
<!-- Start nested content -->
  <li>
     <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
        <li>
          <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-teal" tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons">menu</i>Nested</a>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="color.html">Color</a></li>
                  <li><a href="grid.html">Grid</a></li>
                  <li><a href="helpers.html">Helpers</a></li>
                  <li><a href="media-css.html">Media</a></li>
                  <li><a href="pulse.html">Pulse</a></li>
                  <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                  <li><a href="shadow.html">Shadow</a></li>
                  <li><a href="table.html">Table</a></li>
                  <li><a href="css-transitions.html">Transitions</a></li>
                  <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below with MaterializeCSS

```
<div id="slide-out" class="sidenav" style="transform: translateX(0%);">
   <ul class="collapsible">
    <li class="active">
      <div class="collapsible-header">
        <a href="#/groups/1" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">Group1</a>
      </div> <div class="collapsible-body" style="display: block;">
       <li><a href="#/courses/1" class="waves-effect">Course 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#/courses/2" class="waves-effect">Course 2</a></li>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
     <div class="collapsible-header">
       <a href="#/groups/2" class="">केंद्रीय लोकसेवा  आयोग </a>
     </div> 
     <div class="collapsible-body" style="">
     </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```